# How can I remove duplicate names?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, arraycollection

Consider the follwoing code:

The follwoing code print processorName in this format: 
DC5,DR2,DR3
But when it comes to duplicates it prints as DR3DR3.
I need to remove the duplicate processorName. I am not able to figure it out, how can I do this?

```
 public function processorNameFormat(item:Object, column:GridColumn):String
{
    var processorNames:String = "";
    if (!(item is ProcessOrderDO)) {
        return "";
    }
    var poDestReqList:ArrayCollection = item.processOrderDestinationRequirementDOList ;

    for each(var destReq:ProcessOrderDestinationRequirementDO in poDestReqList)
    {
        if(destReq.processorOID == (poDestReqList[poDestReqList.length-1] as ProcessOrderDestinationRequirementDO).processorOID)
            processorNames +=  destReq.processorName ;
        else
            processorNames +=  destReq.processorName+"," ;
    }
    return processorNames;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove duplicate entries from the result, you should do like this:

```
public function processorNameFormat(item:Object, column:GridColumn):String
{
    var processorNames:String = "";
    if (!(item is ProcessOrderDO)) {
        return "";
    }
    var d:Dictionary=new Dictionary();
    var poDestReqList:ArrayCollection = item.processOrderDestinationRequirementDOList ;

    for each(var destReq:ProcessOrderDestinationRequirementDO in poDestReqList)
    {
        var s:String=destReq.processorName;
        if (d[s]) continue;
        d[s]=true; // fill the dictionary with values to catch duplicates
        if (processorNames=="")
            processorNames +=  destReq.processorName ;
        else
            processorNames +=  ","+destReq.processorName;
    }
    return processorNames;
}
```

You make a `Dictionary` containing found previous processor names, and if there would me a match in the next retrieved processor name, it will be skipped, otherwise added to both dictionary and result string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a more object oriented approach.

This looks a bit overcomplicated:

```
public function processorNameFormat(item:Object, column:GridColumn):String
{
    if (!(item is ProcessOrderDO)) {
        return "";
}
```

if your function only works with a certain type of parameter, why don't you simply declare the parameter to be of that type?

```
public function processorNameFormat(item:ProcessOrderDO, column:GridColumn):String
```

This function mainly operates on this one object passed to it in the parameter. In this case, add this function as a method to the object's class `ProcessOrderDO`:

```
public function processorNameFormat(column:GridColumn):String
```

This simplifies the code a bit:

```
public function processorNameFormat(column:GridColumn):String
{
    var processorNames:String = "";

    for each(var destReq:ProcessOrderDestinationRequirementDO in processOrderDestinationRequirementDOList)
    {
        if(destReq.processorOID == (processOrderDestinationRequirementDOList[processOrderDestinationRequirementDOList.length-1] as ProcessOrderDestinationRequirementDO).processorOID)
            processorNames +=  destReq.processorName ;
        else
            processorNames +=  destReq.processorName+"," ;
    }
    return processorNames;
}
```

It looks like the job of this for loop is to keep track of if the current element is the last one or not, to omit the delimiter at the end. I think it is easier to add the delimiter in every iteration and "subtract" the excess one at the end.

One way way to keep elements of a list unique is to use a data structure that keeps track of that. In as3, the properties of a generic object are of type String and unique.

Here's a little class that does that:

```
class StringSet
{
    private var strings:Object = {};
    private var delimiter:String;

    public function StringSet(delimiter:String = ", ")
    {
        this.delimiter = delimiter;
    }

    public function put(element:String):void
    {
        strings[element] = 0;    
    }

    public function toString():String
    {
        var result:String = "";

        for (var string:String in strings)
            result += string + delimiter;

        return result.substring(0, result.length - delimiter.length);
    }
}
```

With that, the code now looks like this:

```
public function processorNameFormat(column:GridColumn):String
{
    var processorNames:StringSet = new StringSet();

    for each(var destReq:ProcessOrderDestinationRequirementDO in processOrderDestinationRequirementDOList)
    {
        processorNames.put(destReq.processorName);
    }
    return processorNames;
}
```

All the housekeeping of listing the names and making sure they are unique is now in the StringSet class.

I hope the code is self explanatory.
If any of the code is unclear, please ask in a comment.

---

I assume the `DO` stands for data object, which usually do not contain any functionality. But this is functionality that IMO belongs to these objects and thus should be declared in their classes.